# Is it possible to declare a variable as "always global"?

Tags: php, global-variables, global

Is there any way I can define a variable such a way that I don't need to `global $var1;` in every function? Just define it in beginning and keep using where ever needed. I know $GLOBALS exist, but don't want to use it.

Comment: Why not just eliminate the global variable entirely? If you *need* something which acts-as a global variable, you can use a [*static field/property*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) which can be accessed with a class-qualified name but without a special declaration per function.

Comment: that sounds like a very bad idea. Globals should be used very sparingly.

Comment: What's wrong with `$GLOBALS`? It appears to solve the problem you're having (always have variables in the global scope) and furthermore it keeps the variable clearly labeled as global, so you don't accidentally treat it like a disposable variable and overwrite it or some such nonsense.

Comment: I dont have enough time to explain it. Perhaps later. What you need is static variable.

Comment: $GLOBALS $GLOBALS $GLOBALS everywhere seems to make code cluttered, difficult to write. It may be a good idea what I've asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me try to explain why you shouldn't use globals because they are extremely hard to manage. Say a team member overrides an `$ADMIN` variable in a file to be 1, and then all code that references the `$ADMIN` variable will now have the value of 1.

globals are so PHP4, so you need to pick a better design pattern, especially if this is new code.

A way to do this without using the ugly `global` paradigm is to use a class container. This might be known as a "registry" to some people.

```
class Container {
  public static $setting = "foo";
}


echo Container::$setting;
```

This makes it more clear where this variable is located, however it has the weakness of not being able to dynamically set properties, because in PHP you cannot do that statically.

If you don't mind creating an object, and setting dynamic variables that way, it would work.

Comment: This seems a better option, as for not being able dynamically set properties, can I do Containter->set('setting','value'); to change values where needed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the variable as a parameter to that function to avoid using GLOBALS.

The Problematic Scenario (Works ! but avoid it at all costs)

```
<?php
$test = 1;
function test()
{
global $test; 
echo $test; // <--- Prints 1
}
test();
```

The right way...

```
<?php
$test = 1;
function test($test)
{
    echo $test; // <--- Prints 1 
}
test($test); //<--- Pass the $test param here
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour called as superglobal variable. But php has limited predefined list of them: [Superglobals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

So you **cannot** add your own superglobal variable.

[Variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

My suggestions from the most to less radical:

- Edit source code of PHP and add your own superglobals.
- Do not write code at all.
- Do not use PHP (use different language with different variable scope policy).
- Do not use functions (write plain script).
- Use constants instead of variables.
- Use function params instead of using globals.
- Use static variables instead of globals. (`\G::$variable`)

Comment: `Is there any way I can define a variable such a way that I don't need to global $var1; in every function? ` Suggest some way to the OP then.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran , ok. But suggestion is not format of SO. It'l looks like 'There are either too many possible answers...' and 'Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based...'

Comment: "Do not write code at all" - if only I could suggest this more often to some of my team members...